# HTML5 and CSS - custom tags?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a straight HTML 5 website for learning.

Before my CSS might look like:

```
div.BoxHouse {
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#content {
  width: 90%;
  background: url(transwhite.png);
  border: 1px solid #3F4933;
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow:auto;
  top: 10em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

I thought that with HTML5 I could just do this in code:

```
<header>  
<hgroup>
    <content>
    <BoxHouse>
        <h1>HTML 5</h1>  
        <h2>The mark-up language for fun and profit</h2>
    </BoxHouse>
    </content>
</hgroup>
```

Given this as new CSS:

```
BoxHouse {
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

content {
  width: 90%;
  background-image: url('../transwhite.png');
  border: 1px solid #3F4933;
  margin-left: 72px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow:auto;
  top: 10em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

But it clearly doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you creates a rule with 'FloatingBox' ?

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have FloatingBox

Comment: Good Point, it seems I confused my CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use custom tags in HTML5. You should be either selecting the h1, h2 etc directly in your CSS or using classes on them.

```
<header class="content">  
<hgroup class="BoxHouse">
    <h1>HTML 5</h1>  
    <h2>The mark-up language for fun and profit</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Also, is the `background-image: url(transwhite.png);` image a semi transparent white background? If so you can use RGBA colours in CSS3. The is for alpha. So you can use `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` for a 50% transparent white box. The advantage of this over using opacity is the text isn't transparent, it's still clear and solid.

Comment: I thought, like AXL, that we could use custom tags in HTML5. I forget where I heard this from. Are you sure you can't? How do you know?

Comment: Hello, I think if you serve your HTML5 as XML (XHTML5) you could use custom tags but I think you then need to use a custom DTD. I can't remember the exact source as I looked at it a while ago. I wouldn't recommend it though, stick to the existing ones as they have an understood semantic meaning. A new tag wouldn't have any meaning such as a header, article, section - these create the document outline which is the structure of the document, but BoxHouse means nothing to the browser, search engines etc. The HTML5 tags should cover all your needs when combined with classes and IDs.

Comment: You can use custom attributes on tags if you append then with data-  i.e. <h1 data-myattr="value">Heading</h1>. See here for more: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Looks like HTML5 Doctor answered the question here: http://html5doctor.com/your-questions-13/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do makes perfect sense.  But it is not how CSS works.

You can hijack grandfathered tags like <em> and <strong> to keep your html concise, but you cannot create new ones.  Instead use the user friendly
  <span class="myclass">
...